# `tail -n 40 /var/log/apache2/error.log` without `sudo`

Tags: permissions, sudo

Many times during the day I need to inspect my Apache log:

```
sudo tail -n 40 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

I then have to provide my password.

It's a clumsy workflow, so instead I am adding `PATH=$HOME/shortcuts:$PATH` to my `~/.profile` and creating `~/shortcuts/1` that will do it.

However, I need to somehow get around having to type the password each time. (almost each time, there seems to be a 10 minute memory).

I can't just `chmod u+r /var/log/apache2/error.log` -- I think some intermediary folder must have restrictive permissions set.

What is the right way to solve this?

Comment: Just a comment, it might be relevant for your other needs. Instead of creating a script and adding to the $PATH, you can try out alias: http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html

Comment: Your `chmod u+r` command there applies to the user owning `error.log`, as opposed to your current user, so it probably has no effect. I think the best solution is to use `setfacl` to grant your user an exception to the permissions (as described by derobert), or to use `tmux` with `tail -f` running in a pane (as described by Prem).

Answer (score 4):

I can think of many solutions for this specific problem :

(A) Configure sudo access such that your username does not require password for tail command (or for all commands, if you so require)
Refer sudo and sudoers Documentation for this.

(B) Configure sudo access with negative timeout. Default timeout is 5 minutes , after that you will have to reenter the password.
By setting timeout to negative values, you may have to enter the password only once, and sudo will not pester you after that.

(C) Use tmux (or screen)and run the tail command in one pane (or one window).
When-ever you want to see the logs, you can view that pane (or window).

(D) Run a back ground process which sends "tail -f" output to a file in /tmp/ApacheError, which is an exact copy of the log you want to access. Based on your system settings, "tee" may also be required.
Now access the log in /tmp/ApacheError which has read permission for all users.

(E) Consider using apache log filters, which could be used to send Duplicate output to /tmp/ApacheError which will require refering to Apache Documentation.
Now access the log in /tmp/ApacheError which has read permission for all users.

(A) and (B) are security risks. (C) requires tmux (or screen) which may not be available. (D) is safe. (E) may require more research.

Comment: Thank you, I like the look of (E) very much. Isn't there also (F) fiddle group permissions of the log file? (I don't know anything beyond that...)

Comment: Yes (F) is possible, but it was mentioned in your question that you can not do it in your environment, so I did not add it.

Comment: If you want to try (E) , then here is a starting point [[ http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#piped ]] You want want to pipe the logs to tee which will write it to standard location and also write to /tmp/ApacheError which will have read permissions for all users.

Comment: (D) is not quite safe. It is an information leak, it is as insecure as giving a+r permissions to the log file (and a+x to its containing directories).

Comment: @Score_Under , yes , it is an information leak, but it is not a security access leak in a Dev Installation (nobody might get root access via that) ; more-over , that leak can be controlled , eg by chown + chmod , so that only current user can access /tmp/ApacheError , or user could even use a more safe location for this Duplicate file.

Answer (score 4):

`chmod u+r` doesn't do what you apparently think it does; what it actually does is make the file readable by its *owner*. Which, I'm going to guess, it already was.

`chmod o+r` (make file readable by "others", i.e., not owner/group) would probably work, but security argues against this.

Pick one:

1. `ls -l /var/log/apache2/error.log` ... on my (Debian) system, its group is `adm`, and it is `g+r`. The `adm` group exists basically to allow reading log files. So adding myself to that group will let me read it (and other logs). On Debian, that'd be `sudo adduser anthony adm` (where of course `anthony` is my username). NOTE: You'll have to log out and back in for the new group to take effect. In one terminal, `newgrp adm` should work.
2. Use a POSIX ACL to grant yourself read access to that specific file. `sudo setfacl -m u:anthony:r /var/log/apache2/error.log` (use your usename in place of `anthony`). Though depending on how log rotation works on your system, you may need to re-run this after rotate (but you could configure e.g., lograte to do so for you).
3. The various ways to reconfigure sudo in Prem's answer.

Comment: To fix log rotation problem (add give you access to all files in directory (for good or bad)). You can use setfacl with inheritance (defaults) on the directory.

Answer (score 3):

Run `sudo visudo` and add this line:

```
Defaults    timestamp_timeout=-1
```

**-1** = never timeout the password

Also see [man 5 sudoers](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)

Though the above solution attracts security concerns. Please follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) to set up `sudo` to run without password for specific commands.

Comment: same as my solution (B)

Comment: Yes, along with the exact steps how to do it.

Comment: I don't see why this answer has attracted a downvote, it contains useful information.

Comment: @P-i- , strangely , even my answer has got one downvote. I had already upvoted your question. Now, let me also upvote the answers by neuron and by derobert too.

Comment: By not timing out the sudo password, you lose the safety it provides. To retain the safety, you can set up your `sudoers` settings to allow certain commands to be run without having to enter your password. You can add your script that way. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) for details.

Comment: @NZD Agreed.....included your solution into the answer as well & voted your comment as useful